# Toilet sewer gas smell

Tags: plumbing, toilet

We have a sewer gas smell coming from the toilet. The smell is only present when the seat is up, hence it must be coming from inside the toilet bowl. There is a vent stack, and when other fixtures run -- the water level inside the toilet does not get sucked down so that leads me to believe venting is not the issue. The only thing I could think of is perhaps the bowl isn't filling with enough water to begin with? Any ideas? The bathroom has a washing machine, two sinks, and a bath-shower. Also, the vent stack is about 6 inches in diameter, possibly too large?

Comment: Odd, there is a water seal (trap) built into the toilet to prevent sewer gas escape. If it was a venting issue you would usually have some other symptoms: bubbles or burps from the toilet bowl, erratic changes in bowl water level, draining problems from other nearby drains, etc. Have you had any other issues?

Comment: its the only fixture that has an issue. it truly is vexing. although i don't smell anything around the base of the toilet, do you think that a leaky gasket could cause it? there is caulking around the toilet and gaskets on the screws so no gas could escape there.. but if it was leaky it would have to migrate upwards in the toilet and im not sure if there are any channels in which it could do so. probably get a plumber to come by as messing with the wax rings are not my forte.

Answer (score 2):

I had that problem too, we found it was the wax gasket under the toilet, the smell travels, we checked everything else and after I fixed it the smell lingered for a few days and went away the toilet was rocking that was the problem.
Good luck

Comment: I agree that this is likely the problem. I hate dealing with wax rings.